# Change in nature of image: Putting a concave mirror in water vs in air

Tags: water, reflection, refraction, geometric-optics

I was wondering if we put a concave mirror in water, what will be the difference in the image formed by it in air vs water?

**Exception:** Here I mean except when rays come from infinity (e.g., sun) because the rays won't be refracted at all.

*I am considering all cases when the object is near the mirror.*

**My theory:** I think there would be no difference in the position/nature of the image formed, regardless of the fact that the rays now hit the mirror obliquely. I tried to do a similar experiment with a plane mirror. I saw that there wasn't any difference in the position/ nature of the image formed w.r.t the mirror (obviously **the image of the mirror itself would be refracted when it reaches my eyes**). Am I correct in my observation?

Comment: If a light ray strikes a mirror, the angle of reflection will be the same as the angle of incidence. It doesn't matter if the mirror is in air or water. However, when light from the Sun enters the water, it may be refracted. If so, it will hit the mirror at a different angle than if the whole setup was in air.

Comment: @mmesser314 What would be the difference in image formed (water vs air) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would have referred to a lens, according to the lens makers formula, the focal length would have changed. But this is a mirror. So, as long as the medium on both sides of the mirror is same, and the image and object are in the medium with the same optical density and there is no different medium between them, the nature, size and shape of the image will be the same.